# discord.py rewrite how to add limit to spam command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to add a limit to how many messages you can send with this **simple** spam command,
if you don't know how to make a spam command my explanation of the command is in the #'s, this is my code.

```py
@bot.command(aliases=['mimic', 'copy']) #other names for the command
@commands.cooldown(1, 120, commands.BucketType.guild) #adds a cooldown, if the command is used you have to wait 2 minutes to use it again
async def spam(ctx, amount:int, *, message):
    for _ in range(amount): # runs code below a number of times, which would be placed in'()'
        await ctx.send(message) #sends the message you added when running command
# you would use this command like '!spam 20 HAHA' I used '!' as an example prefix and 'HAHA' as an example message
```

this is what I have tried

```py
@bot.command(aliases=['mimic', 'copy', 'repeat'])
@commands.cooldown(1, 120, commands.BucketType.guild)
async def spam(ctx, amount:int = 24, *, message):
    if amount == 25 or >25:
        await ctx.reply('the limit to the amount of messages you can spam is 25')
    elif amount == 24 or <24:
        for _ in range(amount):
            await ctx.send(message)
```

can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I added some comments with this revised code:**

```py
@bot.command(aliases=['mimic', 'copy', 'repeat'])
@commands.cooldown(1, 120, commands.BucketType.guild)
""" `amount` will be a user-inputted integer """
async def spam(ctx, amount:int, *, message):
    """ We can simplify the conditional to: if the amount is less than 25,
        send the message `amount` number of times """
    if amount < 25:
        for _ in range(amount):
            await ctx.send(message)
    """ If `amount` is anything over or equal to 25, send the error message below """
    else:
        await ctx.reply('the limit to the amount of messages you can spam is 25')
```

Comment: Instead of writing a vague "try this" you're expected to explain explain what was wrong with his approach, what you did to the code to fix/improve it...

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, I'm not familiar with discord bot commands, nor have I tried the code myself. When I write "Try this", it's offering a possible solution which I'm not certain is the correct answer or not. If he tries it and accepts the answer, I will edit accordingly to add an explanation. In summary, I don't have enough information on my side to confirm that this is, in fact, the correct solution.

Comment: That's why you should try the code first and get the information to explain the code, even a small explanation would be sufficient. StackOverflow is supposed to be a site were you learn.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I appreciate the advice -- I've added the explanatory comments. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Same to you!

Comment: @ObjectJosh thank you so much for helping me it's really appreciated

Comment: @Shuri My pleasure! If my answer was the answer you were looking for, don't forget to mark it as accepted. Thanks :)